# to the light or in the light

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> The skin of vampires burns in the light.
>
> The skin of vampires burns to the light.

The second doesn't sound idiomatic, but I am not sure if it's still acceptable or not. I have rarely heard it, but I think I saw a few people use "burn to the light". Is it correct or not?

Comment: I have never heard *burns to the light* before. What it sound like is that something burns along the length of something in darkness until the flame *reaches* light (where it might stop). But that clearly doesn't mean the same thing as *burns in the light*. In fact, it's almost the opposite.

Comment: You misheard them saying, 'Turn to the right."